# Incorrect content/mime-type on S3 SVG upload

Tags: assets, s3

I've setup an S3 asset source for images and it's working well for everything but SVGs.

SVGs are uploaded with the default content-type of `binary/octet-stream` where the correct content-type would be `image/svg+xml`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SVG file is probably missing the the XML declaration at the top (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`). PHP's FileInfo detects XML files (which SVG is) without that declaration as text/html files.

Lots of SVG editors/exporters will (annoyingly) omit that.

Comment: Aha! That fixed it. I wonder why PHP doesn't rely on the extension rather than some optional doc type definition.

Anyway, *shakes fist @ Adobe Illustrator team*.

Comment: Probably because extensions can lie. :)  `mv img.jpg img.svg`

Comment: That seems fair, but still it a much more difficult mistake to make than your SVG editor silently omitting an arcane xml node. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Not so much a mistake, but could be used to exploit servers potentially.  i.e. if you restrict uploads based only on file extensions, but then rename `mybadscript.exe` to `cutekitten.jpg`, you've delivered a payload and now just need to find a way to execute it.

Comment: it is working for me. It really great solutions

Answer (score -1):

On old versions of python, the python library mimetypes didnt have a definition for svg file types.

See this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue19377

I added `'.svg' : 'image/svg+xml',` into the `types_map` in `mimetypes.py` and then the aws cli got the correct type for SVGs.